# Change numpy array under condition from another array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I'm new to python and still trying to find a good way to solve this problem:

I have a 2D array `label` stores the labels (from 0 to 10; 0 is the background, 1 is for the tree, etc.) of an image. From this array, I want to create an RGB image `rgb = np.zeros((height, width , 3), np.uint8)` on which each pixel in `rgb` will have the colour depends on the value of `label`. For example, `rgb[4, 8] = green_color` if `label[4, 8] = 1`. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an array named `colors` of shape `11 x 3` holding all possible colors for the `11` labels (as label ranges from `0` to `10`), here's one approach using [`integer indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing) -

```
img = colors[label.ravel()].reshape(label.shape+(3,)).astype('uint8')
```

Sample run to verify output -

```
In [58]: label
Out[58]: 
array([[ 2,  4,  0],
       [ 2,  9, 10],
       [ 6, 10, 10],
       [ 4,  0,  4],
       [ 1,  4, 10],
       [ 8,  1,  7],
       [ 9,  8,  0]])

In [59]: colors
Out[59]: 
array([[ 28, 175,  15],
       [  0, 255,   0], # Green color at label = 1
       [228,  12, 104],
       [198, 135,  99],
       [126, 124, 222],
       [ 35,  78,  14],
       [ 64,  61,   0],
       [ 34,  49, 147],
       [240,   1, 174],
       [252,   1, 181],
       [171, 114, 191]])

In [60]: img = colors[label.ravel()].reshape(label.shape+(3,))

In [61]: label[4,0]
Out[61]: 1

In [62]: img[4,0]
Out[62]: array([  0, 255,   0])

In [63]: label[5,1]
Out[63]: 1

In [64]: img[5,1]
Out[64]: array([  0, 255,   0])
```

Comment: Good point - I had not benchmarked `np.choose`. `np.take` seems to be even faster (see my update).

Comment: Actually you don't need all of that `ravel`ing and `reshape`ing -  `colors[labels]` will work fine (it's more or less equivalent to `colors.take(labels, axis=0)`)

Comment: @ali_m Exactly! I just tested that as you posted the comment :) Add that to your solution!

Answer (score 1):

The following works, thanks to [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
label = np.asarray(( (0,1,1,1), (2,2,0,1) ))
# label will be:
# array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
#        [2, 2, 0, 1]])

# or (0, 255, 0) or so
green_color = np.asarray((0,1,0))

# initialize empty image
img = np.zeros((2,4,3))

# set pixels where label==1 to green
img[label == 1] = green_color
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`np.choose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html):

```
gen = np.random.RandomState(0)
labels = gen.randint(3, size=(5, 6))  # random labels between 0 and 2

print(repr(labels))
# array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2],
#        [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2],
#        [1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1]])

colors = np.array([[255, 0, 0],     # red
                   [0, 255, 0],     # green
                   [0, 0, 255]])    # blue

rgb = labels[..., None].choose(colors)

# labels[0, 1] == 1, so rgb[0, 1] should be [0, 255, 0] (i.e. green)

print(repr(rgb[0, 1]))
# array([  0, 255,   0])
```

---

Another (much faster!) option would be [`np.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html), e.g.:

```
rgb = colors.take(labels, axis=0)
```

This can be done more succinctly (but not quite as quickly) by using `labels` as an [index array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing):

```
rgb = colors[labels]
```

Some benchmarking:

```
# my original answer
In [1]: %%timeit colors = np.random.randint(256, size=(11, 3)); labels = np.random.randint(11, size=(512, 512))                                                                                                                               
labels[..., None].choose(colors)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 52 ms per loop

# Divakar's answer
In [2]: %%timeit colors = np.random.randint(256, size=(11, 3)); labels = np.random.randint(11, size=(512, 512))
colors[labels.ravel()].reshape(labels.shape+(3,))
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.44 ms per loop

# using take
In [3]: %%timeit colors = np.random.randint(256, size=(11, 3)); labels = np.random.randint(11, size=(512, 512))
colors.take(labels, axis=0)
   ....: 
The slowest run took 4.96 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an 
intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 ms per loop

# using integer array indexing
In [4]: %%timeit colors = np.random.randint(256, size=(11, 3)); labels = np.random.randint(11, size=(512, 512))
   ....: colors[labels]
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.19 ms per loop
```

Comment: Ah lovely! I didn't know `take` had `axis` option, really good!

Comment: `take` is really fast, faster than indexing itself! Do you know why? Some internal optimizations?

Comment: @Divakar I suppose that `take` can be simpler due to the fact that it only supports integer index arrays, whereas the normal `[...]` syntax has to deal with any combination of slice objects, int scalars, boolean index arrays etc. I've never looked into the implementations, though.